# How long a PID has been running (taking multiple inputs)

Tags: posix, sh

Tonight I tried to write a POSIX shell script which would allow me to check how long a process is running (via it's ID) and be able to handle multiple inputs:

```
#!/bin/sh 

is_this_a_number()
{
    if [ "$1" -eq "$1" ] 2> /dev/null
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

does_pid_exist()
{
    if ps --pid "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

how_long_pid_has_been_running()
{
    ps --pid "$1" --format etime=
}

trim_leading_and_trailing_spaces()
{
    awk '{$1=$1;print}'
}


arg_pos=0

while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
do

    arg_val="$1"
    arg_pos=$((arg_pos + 1))

    if ! is_this_a_number "$arg_val"
    then

        echo "The argument at position $arg_pos is not a number."

    else

        echo "Process ID $arg_val"

        if ! does_pid_exist "$arg_val"
        then

            echo "This process does not exist."

        else

            how_long_pid_has_been_running "$arg_val" | trim_leading_and_trailing_spaces

        fi

    fi

    printf "\\n"

    shift

done
```

Usage:

```
./how-long-pid-is-running 1 10078 c 40545454
```

Where 10078 is an instance of Chrome.

The output is as follows:

```
Process ID 1
09:04:31

Process ID 10078
07:32:32

The argument at position 3 is not a number.

Process ID 40545454
This process does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- GNU long options are not POSIX, so instead of `ps --pid "$1" --format etime=`, write `ps -p "$1" -o etime=`.
- `kill -s 0 "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1` is much faster than `ps --pid "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1`, partly because `kill` is a builtin in most shells. Signal 0 is used to test for the existence of a process without sending it a signal.
- Consider redirecting the `echo` messages to the appropriate output streams, i.e. `stdout` and `stderr`.
- `is_this_a_number`, `does_pid_exist`: these are used directly in `if` clauses, so it'd read more naturally if they are renamed to `is_a_number` and `pid_exists`.
- A minor point here, but I'd reverse the `if`-`else` statements to remove the `!` negations.
- Another minor point: during the short time span between testing the existence of a PID and querying the elapsed time since the process with that PID was started, the process with that PID could have finished running or even been substituted with a newly spawned one. You could avoid that by running the second command first, saving the output in a variable and then check for nullness, like thus:

  ```
  echo "Process ID $arg_val"
  running_time=$(how_long_pid_has_been_running "$arg_val" 2>/dev/null | 
      trim_leading_and_trailing_spaces)
  if [ -z "${running_time}" ]
  then
      echo "This process does not exist."
  else
      echo "${running_time}"            
  fi
  ```
- I've seen you write `printf "\\n"` in another post also, so I'm curious: is it any different from `printf "\n"`? And in any case, an `echo` would do the job just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Functions forward the exit status of the last command, so the pattern

```
f()
{
    if $command
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```

can be replaced with

```
f()
{
    $command
}
```

unless you really must force all error returns to 1.